# Opening fxml file for certain time and go back to the main screen?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How do I display an fxml file for some seconds and close that fxml file and return to the mainpage.fxml?

I have tried to add hideThispage method to the initialize method in the controller class of the fxml but I guess the initialize methods just runs before the class is actually loaded so I cannot run this code.

```
@FXML
public void hideThisPage() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Window window = new Stage();
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
    pause.setOnFinished(e -> window.hide());
    pause.play();
    FxmlDisplay fxmlDisplay = new FxmlDisplay();
    fxmlDisplay.stageSelection("View/Main.fxml");
}
```

To return to the main.fxml or any fxml I have a method that I call:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
```

In my case, I have a print button in my printreceipt.fxml file that prints the contents. Then it switches to the printpage.fxml ( i am able to switch to the page) But my problem is the printpage.fxml is supposed to be displayed only for 5 seconds and close. then it should go back to main.fxml. how and where do I call the hidethisPage() method?

```
@FXML
    void printRandomTicket(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, JRException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        FxmlDisplay fxmlDisplay = new FxmlDisplay();
        ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        fxmlDisplay.stageSelection("/View/Dialogs/PrintingTicket.fxml");
        GenerateTicket generateTicket = new GenerateTicket();
        generateTicket.generateTicket();
        PrintTicket printTicket = new PrintTicket();
        printTicket.printTicket();
}
```

I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem please? Using a `PauseTransition` is a good approach for this, so the issue you're having is not entirely clear.

Comment: Why do you think `initialize` runs "before the class is actually loaded"? There isn't really a class and `initialized` is executed at the very end of the loading process, i.e. just before the value is returned from `load`. Please note that starting an animation in the `initialize` method may not be the best idea, since you cannot postpone showing the scene this way without receiving unexpected results. (not sure what the `FxmlDisplay` class in your code is responsible for btw and `window` is never shown on screen...)